# how to get specified text pos through xpdf or mupdf?

Tags: pdf, text, extract, mupdf, xpdf

I want to extract some specified text in pdf files and the text position.

I know xpdf and mupdf can parse pdf files,so i think they may help me to fulfill this task.

But how to use these two lib to get text position?

Comment: what do you mean by text position?

Comment: @DanD.Text position means the first character position in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mupdf** comes with a couple of tools, one being `pdfdraw`.

If you use pdfdraw with the `-tt` option, it will generate an `XML` containing all characters and their exact positioning information. 
From there you should be able to find what you need.

Comment: In newer versions it is called mudraw.c and the trail leads to structured-text.h and stext-output.c, very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using a Python binding for MuPDF, here is a Python solution using PyMuPDF (I am one of its developers):

```
import fitz                     # the PyMuPDF module
doc = fitz.open("input.pdf")    # PDF input file
page = doc[n]                   # page number n (0-based)
wordlist = page.getTextWords()  # gives you a list of all words on the
# page, together with their position info (a rectangle containing the word)

# or, if you only are interested in blocks of lines belonging together:
blocklist = page.getTextBlocks()

# If you need yet more details, use a JSON-based output, which also gives
# images and their positions, as well as font information for the text.
tdict = json.loads(page.getText("json"))
```

We are on GitHub if you are interested.

Comment: if you don't need all words, will it be faster to use `search` method that also provides position, than use `extractWORDS()`?

Comment: @edvard_munch - not really, because both methods create the same intermediate object ``TextPage`` and then perform their specific tasks using properties of that object. The textpage does all the work of extracting (text **and** images as required).

Comment: As per my original answer, please also note, that there is a new option for ``page.getText("dict")`` which directly produces a Python dictionary -- instead using an intermediate JSON. So the respective statement would just be ``tdict = page.getText("dict")``, which needs no JSON and is several times faster ...